# How can I debug ls -l being slow?

Tags: ls

I'm on ubuntu 16.04, which was installed by the university where I work. `ls` works fine, but `ls -l` very often hangs for 4-5 seconds. I've found some sources saying this could be due to mounted shares and such, but I have no mounted filesystems on my computer (other than my harddrive of course).

The IT people are saying they don't have time to debug this, so I'm wondering how I could go about finding where the issue lies? Without really knowing enough about how `ls` works, I slightly suspect that my OS was configured such that `ls -l` needs to talk to an authentication server, via samba. How could I check this?

Comment: Samba? I thought you said you had no remotely mounted file systems. Please [edit] your question and give us some more details. Does this happen no matter where you try `ls -l`? Is it consistent? Do similar commands like `find . -maxdepth 1 -ls` or `stat *` also hang? What is the output of `type ls`? What is the output of `df`? Does the disk make a lot of noise?

Comment: First step: run `strace -T ls -l ` and see which call takes a long time. Do this in a few different directories to get and idea for when it does and doesn't happen.

Comment: @terdon good point: it seems I've slightly misunderstood how samba works. I log in via samba authentication, and you're right that there are actually some mounted filesystems. I will play around for a bit with the commands you and Gilles gave me and report back.

Comment: try `ls -ln` it should be faster. I guess uid <=> real name mapping is responsible for initial delay.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The best way to see what an application is doing is to run it through a debugger. In case of Linux systems it is usually `gdb`.
The fastest way to figure out what to look for in the debugger is to first run the application with `strace`, it will show you all system calls being used and you will be able to see if there is something system related that takes time. 
Run: `strace ls -l`

Debugging `/bin/ls` which is a part of the `coreutils` package will require you to install the debugging symbols for that package. You will need to add a repository to do that, explained [in this answer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/427318/how-can-i-install-a-debug-build-for-coreutils).
Running: `gdb --args ls -l` will get you into debugging. More info on that [is here.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2069367/how-to-debug-using-gdb)

Comment: You might want to add some explanation on how to run a command through `gdb`. It isn't obvious to the uninitiated.

Comment: Tracing `ls -n` might prove informative, too.